# Adding contact address in Odoo

Tags: odoo, contacts, odoo-12

I am working with Odoo External API version 12. For nor I am using res.partner to add customers.

But there are few points:

- There are 2 kind of customers. B2B and B2C
- When customer is B2B it has to take the company name as a main name, and customer name as a contact address.

In this case I have 2 questions:

1. Adding it as individual or company is better approach? Because when I am adding as a company and customer as a contact address it is creating totally new company. However I just need to create that company under my main company.
2. How I can create individual + contact address in the same request.

Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its better to add as separate company and contact